# what will the Mathematical function for the following condition?

Tags: notation

I am having `n` inputs whose value is in between `x1,x2,x3,x4,x5`.

I want to know what will be the mathematical representation or formula for the following conditions considering the above details:

1) The number of input is `n` and has the value range between `x1 to x5`.
2) checking the `n` inputs one by one and performing summation of the each values based on the similar values. For example, if the values are `[x1,x2,x1,x4,x5]`
then `x1=2,x2=1,x4=1,x5=1`
3)Finally comparing the values and resulting the highest values as output. For example: in the above example, `x1 = 2`. Hence, the comparison output should give `x1`.

Kindly, let me know the representation of the above.

Comment: You could write $\max(x_1, \ldots , x_n)$. There's no mathematics that will "tell you the answer". Your profile suggests this may be a programming question. Then call your function "$\max$" (if there isn't one in the language already) and code the algorithm with a loop or other language construct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you.

Comment: @EthanBolker actually it a kind of mathematic logic. Which I am trying to write down and then will code accordingly.

Comment: When you say that the $n$ inputs are "in between" $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ do you mean that the values of the inputs lie in the set $X=\{ x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5\}$? Also you appear to be using each $x_k$ to mean the particular element of the set $X$ and simultaneously the *number of times* the element $x_k$ appears among the $n$ inputs. Would it not be clearer to let that be some function of $x_k$ so that $N(x_k)$ is the number of times that $x_k$ occurs in the list of $n$ inputs? Then you want to find the $x_k$ for which $N(x_k)$ is the maximum? Or have I completely misunderstood your question?

Comment: Sorry but this is close to trivial, why are you asking ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I didn't got you. trivial? I have problem hence I am asking....

Comment: No, you explained the procedure that leads to the result, which is easy. So it is unclear what problem you are having.

Comment: @JafferWilson: did you disregard my answer ?

Comment: @JafferWilson Have I understood your question or should I delete my answer?

Comment: @YvesDaoust my apology, it was typo mistake. 
I mean this :  what I am looking for the mathematical function of whatever I had explained to you so that I can use this as a Activation function in Neural Networking

Comment: @Wyllich Kindly, don't delete your response.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales You had completely understood it rightly. I repeat, Yes, values of the inputs lie in the set X={x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}.

Comment: Please everybody mention what you all didn't understood, so that I can clarify. Without understanding how people have given answers, I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't know for the number of inputs as you haven't specified how the input looks like but for the second condition, if the inputs are $i_1, i_2, ... i_n$, you may check:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^5(i_k-x_j) =0$$

2) Iteratively, if $0 < x_1 < ... < x_5$

$$ x_5 = \sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor \frac{i_k}{x_5} \rfloor$$

then

$$ x_4 = \sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor \frac{i_k}{x_4} \rfloor - x_5$$

At the end, you may have quite  a convoluted formula :

$$x_j = \sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor\frac{i_k}{x_j}\rfloor - (\sum_{l=j+1}^5 \sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor \frac{i_k}{x_l}\rfloor)$$

3) I am out of  idea to find the max. Perhaps, if we are allowed to use $n$...

Comment: for the max we can define function $z=f(x,y)=\lbrace x, $if $x\ge y$; $y$, if $y>x\rbrace$ Then $max=f(f(f(x_1,x_2),f(x_3,x_4)),x_5)$

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called the *mode* of a distribution, i.e. the entry that has the largest frequency (which might not be unique).

You obtain it by counting - computing an histogram, one counter per possible value - and searching for the largest count.

Comment: Very thoughtful, I am willing to work out the mathematical function for this.
eg : I am providing say n input with a any integer value between 1-5, and wanted to discover which vale from 1-5 is inputted maximum time.
means output will be just one value from the range of 1-5.

Comment: You were asking for the "mathematical function". I am telling you. So what ???

Comment: It seems your answer is quite nearer to what I have asked. I am still checking.